# How to create an object which has a property that can only have a certain values

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, oop, mvvm

initially it looked a simple problem to me but the more I think more I am confused on what is the best way to achieve what I want.

We are making a `WPF` application following `MVVM`

so scenario is -

we have a class say `MyClass` which has a property of type `Complex`, it also has a property called `Category` of type `int`.

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public Property Category As Integer
    Public Property MyProperty As Complex

End Class
```

Now `MyProperty` can have a certain values only based on its category.
We have a list of an object which contains all possible values of MyProperty against each category.

My question is considering MVVM, where this list of possible items be placed?
should we make it part of the object like a new property which has all possible values of `MyProperty` and then have a check when we set the property ? or somewhere else ?

```
Public Property AvailablePropertyValues As IEnumerable(Of Complex)
```

Keeping it in object makes it real simple when we bind this object to view, as we don't have to filter the list but I know its trivial to filter lists for each item and we should not consider ease of creating view while modelling our objects.

Any ideas on how to model my object ?

Comment: You probably want it in whatever class has the property so you can validate the values when they get set

Comment: Dependency properties may be helpful in that case

Comment: @Muds In this case yes. You probably also want MyClass to implement IDataErrorInfo for your data validation, unless you want to use validation rules instead. I don't have much experience with those so you would have to look that up

Comment: No matter what you do, I would highly suggest you create a ComplexList class that will take care of filtering. Removing the filtering logic from MyClass. That class could also have a function ComplexList.IsAvailable(ByVal category As Integer, ByVal property As ...). That class could also cache the lists. If Complex is a static object, personally, in MyClass, I would have a property called MyPropertyId and a readonly property called MyProperty that returns Complex based on the id.

Comment: i am still trying to figure out this new class, thanks for suggestion lotus

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have all the data that shows up on the screen come from the viewmodel via bindings, that includes the possible choices you want to select from, and the actual selected value, and then validate either through the setters (that's what i see setters to be used for, to insert custom validation logic based on the input value) or nicer, by implementing an IValidatableObject interface so you can also have UI notification of invalid values.

For IValidatableObject you can see the topic http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3 or http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/2012/03/19/ivalidatableobject-and-idataerrorinfo/